# how do I enable the /refresh Actuator endpoint and get around CSRF restrictions?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

In the WebSecurityConfig.java in our project

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurererAdapter {
   @Override
   p void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
       .and.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
   }
}
```

I have installed the @RefreshScope on my pojo:

```
@Configuration
@Data
@RefreshScope
public class MyProperties {
   private String myName;
   private String myAddress;
   private String myCity;
   .....
}
```

Spring Boot Actuator is installed.  Spring Security is providing https and SSL.  I can get to all of the GET actuator endpoints, but when I try to do a call to http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh (a POST), I get a 403 Refused.

In looking around, I saw that the default stuff doesn't allow POSTs.  This works if I disable csrf(), but not if it is enabled (which is a requirement for the product).

Could someone help me understand what is going on?  Has anyone else done this?  Can this be done without disabling CSRF entirely?

Thanks,
Winona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify what endpoints on which you want to disable CSRF. For example: `csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/actuator/**")`. Doing so disables CSRF prorection for any request that starts with `/actuator/`.